# VBScript to add code to Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have the task to add a `WorkBook_Open()` method to numerous Excel Workbooks. I managed to write a script which adds a module (marked red) with the needed code lines but I need it in the `DieseArbeitsmappe`(marked green) to autostart when the workbook is opened.

[image: Project setup]

```
Set xlmodule = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
strCode = _
    "Sub WorkBook_Open()" & vbCr & _
    "   Application.Run (""'CommonMacro.xlsm'!Workbook_Open"")" & vbCr & _
    "End Sub"
xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode
```

This is the code I have right now. I'm pretty sure that the mistake is at line 1 when setting the xlmodule but I can't figure how to reference to `DieseArbeitsmappe`. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use `xlmodule` as a variable name.  It's already defined as an Excel constant. I'd call it something like `component` instead.  The `VBComponents` collection has an indexer that accepts either the ordinal index of the component *or* the component name.  In your case it would be easiest to just use the name:

```
Set component = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("DieseArbeitsmappe")
code = _
    "Sub WorkBook_Open()" & vbCr & _
    "   Application.Run ""'CommonMacro.xlsm'!Workbook_Open""" & vbCr & _
    "End Sub"
component.CodeModule.AddFromString code
```

Note that it's usually not best practice to call an event handler directly like that.  If you need to reuse the functionality, you should pull it out of the handler and then have `Workbook_Open` call the extracted `Sub`.