# VBScript to loop through Excel-files and change macro

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I already posted a closely related question last week [VBScript to add code to Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537940/vbscript-to-add-code-to-excel-workbook) which got solved by a fellow programmer. But I ran into the next problem with that task:

With the following code, I try to loop through a folder of Excel files then open them one by one and change the macro in `DieseArbeitsmappe`. This works fine for the first file but the second ends with this error message.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Eds.png)

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = "P:\Administration\Reports\operativ\Tagesbericht\templates\START07\TestTabsiNeu\"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files  
  Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFolder & objFile.Name)

    Set component = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("DieseArbeitsmappe")

       strCode = _
       "Sub WorkBook_Open() 'just for testing" & vbCr & _
       "   Application.Run (""'CommonMacro.xlsm'!Workbook_Open"")" & vbCr & _
       "End Sub"
        component.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode

    objWorkbook.SaveAs "P:\Administration\Reports\operativ\Tagesbericht\templates\START07\TestTabsiNeu\" & objFile.Name
    objExcel.Quit

    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set component = Nothing

Next

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Line 10 is `Set component = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("DieseArbeitsmappe")`

Another problem I will face soon is that sometimes the `VBComponent` is called `ThisWorkbook`. So I will have to introduce `if-else` based on the Error code thrown by Line 10. Or is there a better solution for this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can do that, but write a dedicated function to return you the appropriate component. Put error handling inside this function (try getting VBComponents("DieseArbeitsmappe") if error get "ThisWorkbook" etc.)

Comment: side note: replace `objWorkbook.SaveAs "P:\Administration\Reports\operativ\Tagesbericht\templates\START07\TestTabsiNeu\"` with `objWorkbook.SaveAs sFolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a perfect answer, as I am more confused than I am certain of the exact problem... However hopefully this will help.

The command `objExcel.Quit` is going to close the Excel application.

I'm not quite sure how the code (in the next loop) then successfully executes

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFolder & objFile.Name)
```

when the `objExcel` application has been quit.  However, the `.Visible` and `.DisplayAlerts` will no longer be set True/False. The latter could cause your failure in line 10.

Therefore I suggest replacing

```
 objExcel.Quit
```

with

```
objWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Thank you. Replacing `objExcel.Quit` with `objWorkbook.Close` solved the main problem.