# VBScript to change Excel macro for all files in a folder

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

My current problem is closely related to questions [VBScript to loop through Excel-files and change macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631259/vbscript-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-change-macro/42631726#42631726) and [VBScript to add code to Excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537940/vbscript-to-add-code-to-excel-workbook). So the problem I want to solve is looping through all the Excel files in a folder and change the macro, which in some files is called `DieseArbeitsmappe` and in some `ThisWorkbook`. The following code opens every Excel and saves it but doesn't change the VBComponent. The issue has to be with the functions that return the component because the code I posted last time I made work.

This is my actual code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = "P:\Administration\Reports\operativ\Tagesbericht\templates\START07\TestTabsiNeu\"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next
For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFolder & objFile.Name)

    Set component = extractedComponent(objWorkbook)

    strCode = _
    "Sub WorkBook_Open()" & vbCr & _
    "   Application.Run (""'CommonMacro.xlsm'!Workbook_Open"")" & vbCr & _
    "End Sub"
    component.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode

    objWorkbook.SaveAs "P:\Administration\Reports\operativ\Tagesbericht\templates\START07\TestTabsiNeu\" & objFile.Name
    objWorkbook.Close
    Set component = Nothing
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing       
Next

objExcel.Quit
Set objFSO = Nothing


Function extractedComponent(objWorkbook)
    Err.Clear
    Set comp = objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("DieseArbeitsmappe")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        extractedComponent = comp
        Exit Function
    Else
        Err.Clear
        Set altComp = objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            extractedComponent = altComp
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vbs
Set extractedComponent = comp
Set extractedComponent = altComp
```

To return the object from the function, you should be `Set`ting the return value such that the function call understands it is returning an object, & can properly assign it to your `component` variable.

I would also recommend turning on errors in order to get a better look at what might be failing.